# Problem when exporting from Blender to Unity 3D?

Tags: export, unity

I'm having a problem when trying to import my character to the Unity Engine. It gives me message:

`Unable to open Assets/untitled.fbx: Check external application preferences`

Can anyone please tell my what's wrong and how to fix it?

I followed the steps from a tutorial I watched: I exported my character as a .fbx file and unchecked *Include Default Take*, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's an issue with the export itself. Try exporting it to a different type (unity supports .blends, so you can simply drag and drop a .blend into the editor).

Comment: @CharlesL Thanks a lot it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blender exporters sometimes don't work perfectly. However, Unity supports .blend files, so you can simply drag and drop the .blend file into the Unity project.